# How to add accordion pane in asp.net mvc 4 using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am creating simple web application using ASP.NET MVC 4. I am using razor code. I have
HomeController.cs, Index.cshtml,_Layout.cshtml files. I have put the code in them like:
_Layout.cshtml:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#accordion").accordion();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p class="site-title">@Html.ActionLink("Practice", "Index", "Home")</p>
                </div>
                <div class="float-right">
                    <section id="login">
                        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
                    </section>
                    <nav>
                        <ul id="menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div id="body">
            @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET MVC Application</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

Index.cshtml:

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@section featured {
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
                <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
            </hgroup>
            <p>
                To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit
                <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">http://asp.net/mvc</a>.
                The page features <mark>videos, tutorials, and samples</mark> to help you get the most from ASP.NET MVC.
                If you have any questions about ASP.NET MVC visit
                <a href="http://forums.asp.net/1146.aspx/1?MVC" title="ASP.NET MVC Forum">our forums</a>.
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
}
<h3>We suggest the following:</h3>
<div id="accordion">  
    <h1><a href="#1">Section 1</a></h1>  
    <div>In section 1</div>  
    <h1><a href="#2">Section 2</a></h1>  
    <div>In section 2</div>  
</div>
```

I am trying to create accordion pane like on page - http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

So please Help me I will be so thankful to that person.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working fine. As you've already added the required jQuery libraries to the page header, you should remove the line below:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Sj7Mh/

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. But still i was having problems so i put it on top n it worked. It was like `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")`
                                `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you jquery is place before jquery UI, you could refer more detail  [here](http://instinctcoder.com/asp-net-mvc-4-jquery-accordion/) for step by step to on how create the accordion in MVC